# Plotting Polygon returns " 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom' "

Tags: geopandas, cartopy

I am trying to plot several polygons as overlays on an existing map with cartopy. However, I receive the following error `AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'`.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
ax.stock_img()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

shape_feature = ShapelyFeature([africa.geometry], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor="lime", edgecolor='black', lw=1)

ax.add_feature(shape_feature)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geodataframe `africa` you have just created has a method `.plot()`. So that you can plot it with an option `ax=ax` that instructs the renderer to use the axis you created to plot on it.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

africa.plot(ax=ax)

# Bad code
#shape_feature = ShapelyFeature([africa.geometry], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor="lime", edgecolor='black', lw=1)
#ax.add_feature(shape_feature)

plt.show()
```

[image: africa]

**Answer to the updated question**

The new version of the code:-

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
axis_proj = ccrs.Mollweide()

ax = plt.axes(projection=axis_proj)
ax.stock_img()

for ea in africa['geometry']:
    feat = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature([ea], latlon_proj, facecolor="lime", edgecolor='black', lw=0.2)
    ax.add_feature(feat)

#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: africa4]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am aware that I can plot GeoDataFrames via `df.plot()` but I would like to add geometries from a GeoDataFrame to an existing cartopy map. Unfortunately, your answer does not help me with that.

Comment: @Stücke Answer is updated. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works :) How did you pick the different ccrs? When I choose another ccrs (`ccrs.Orthographic()`; the same for both layers) it does not work anymore.

Comment: @Stücke Better ask as a new question.

Comment: DOne https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981605/shape-disappears-after-changing-the-ccrs