# Shape disappears after changing the CCRS

Tags: geopandas, cartopy

Follwing [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68973011/5696601), I am plotting the countries of the African continent on the earth sphere:

```py
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
axis_proj = ccrs.Mollweide()

ax = plt.axes(projection=axis_proj)
ax.stock_img()

for ea in africa['geometry']:
    
    feat = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(
        [ea],
        latlon_proj,
        facecolor="lime",
        edgecolor='black',
        lw=0.2
        )
    
    ax.add_feature(feat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However when I change `latlon_proj` and `axis_proj` to `ccrs.Orthographic()`, the African continent disappears:

```py
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

latlon_proj = ccrs.Orthographic()
axis_proj = ccrs.Orthographic()

ax = plt.axes(projection=axis_proj)
ax.stock_img()

for ea in africa['geometry']:
    
    feat = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(
        [ea],
        latlon_proj,
        facecolor="lime",
        edgecolor='black',
        lw=0.2
        )
    
    ax.add_feature(feat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I keep the African continent when changing the CCRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wrong use of CRS in the code. Here is the correct version of it.

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[(world['continent'] == 'Africa')]

latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()  ## The correct CRS
axis_proj = ccrs.Orthographic()

ax = plt.axes(projection=axis_proj)
ax.stock_img()

for ea in africa['geometry']:

    feat = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(
        [ea],
        latlon_proj,
        facecolor="lime",
        edgecolor='black',
        lw=0.2
        )

    ax.add_feature(feat)

plt.show()
```

[image: africa]

Comment: `latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()` is used to signify the coordinate system that the data is used.  `axis_proj = ccrs.Orthographic()` is used to signify the map projection to use on the plot.

Comment: Great, thank you. I guess I have to look into the exact meaning of both.